# Unable to pass data between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Is anyone able to tell me why I am unable to pass data between the view controllers?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

I get the object from the NSMutableArray and then access the placeId property. Then I look to pass this to the next view controller (BIDCCreateViewController) but I am unable to. Null is always logged from the next viewcontroller.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BIDDCCreateViewController *biddccCreateViewController = [[BIDDCCreateViewController alloc]init];
    BIDBusinessModel *tempObjStore = [self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    biddccCreateViewController.placeId = tempObjStore.placeId;
    NSLog(@"tempObjStore in didselectrow: %@", tempObjStore.placeId);

}

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDDCCreateViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *placeId;
@end

#import "BIDDCCreateViewController.h"

@implementation BIDDCCreateViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"SUCCESSFULLY PASSED PLACE ID: %@", self.placeId);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

My output is from the logs is as follows:

```
2013-09-24 14:01:49.208 CouponLocation[827:a0b] tempObjStore in didselectrow: 1f068b8d2b6a13daf9be5eddee5cb32585b76377
2013-09-24 14:01:49.209 CouponLocation[827:a0b] SUCCESSFULLY PASSED PLACE ID: (null)
```

Nothing is being passed. When I set the string in the BIDCCCreateViewConroller and log it, it works fine. As you can see the string in the viewcontroller I am trying to pass from is fine. This is demonstrated in the 'tempOjcStore in didselectrow' log. So there is a string there but it is not being passed and there does not appear to be anything wrong with the string in the other viewcontroller because I am able to change this from within and log.

Somehow it is not being transmitted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have u used segue? How you show second view controller?

Comment: CRDave - BIDDCCreateViewController is my 2nd view controller I am trying to segue to.

Comment: Than follow answer of @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value on a wrong object: `biddccCreateViewController` is local to your method, it is not the controller that gets displayed later, when the segue is fired (or whatever is the method through which you open the actual view controllrer).

Instead of placing your code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, place your code in `prepareForSegue`. You can access the target view controller from there, like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"openDetails"]){
       UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) sender;
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
       BIDDCCreateViewController *biddccCreateViewController = (BIDDCCreateViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
       BIDBusinessModel *tempObjStore = [self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       biddccCreateViewController.placeId = tempObjStore.placeId;
   }
}
```

Finally, the proper place to display the value of `placeId` is `viewWillAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`, because loading of the view happens before you can set `placeId` on the controller.

Comment: I will try this but just looking at it, the 'indexPath.row' will not work, I am guessing. That is how I access the correct element of my NSmutableArray. I believe that this solution won't compile (I'm guessing, but I shall try). Can't I just work with my current solution. How do I make it so the method is not local. Perhaps I will declare in the @interface. I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @Anthony I just noticed that - take a look at the edit. `self.tableView` should be your `UITableView` object, and `@"openDetails"` should be the actual segue name in your project.

Comment: In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I set a class variable (named segueRow) which is then accessed in `prepareForSegue` to select the proper row in my NSArray. Then I pass the data on to the ViewController which is being segued to.

Answer (score 1):

I think when You are passing the value of tempObjStore.placeId into BIDDCCreateViewController from BIDBusinessModel, may be value being passed before opening BIDDCCreateViewController thats why you are getting NULL value in BIDDCCreateViewController.

Follow the example code

In BIDDCCreateViewController

-(void) ViewDidLoad

{
[self performSelector:@selector(getValue) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0 ];

}

-(void) getValue

{

NSLog(@"SUCCESSFULLY PASSED PLACE ID: %@", self.placeId);

}

Answer (score 0):

Where are you pushing your BIDDCCreateViewController view ?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BIDDCCreateViewController *biddccCreateViewController = [[BIDDCCreateViewController alloc]init];
    BIDBusinessModel *tempObjStore = [self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    biddccCreateViewController.placeId = tempObjStore.placeId;
    NSLog(@"tempObjStore in didselectrow: %@", tempObjStore.placeId);


   [self.navigationController pushViewController:biddccCreateViewController];
}
```

and you refresh your view controller it's going to work :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"SUCCESSFULLY PASSED PLACE ID: %@", self.placeId);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I now see the error 'No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'pushViewController'. :-S

Answer (score 0):

You create `BIDDCCreateViewController` as a local variable, but the actual controller that gets pushed in the navigation stack may be a different one. Maybe you are setting a property for the wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to push your biddccCreateViewController in the -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath as you are creating it locally. Add a step to push the view controller in this method.